# onClick toggle radio and label elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button, toggle

This is what i tried.

```
<form method="POST">
<label>YES</label>
<input type="radio" name="yes">
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['yes']) === 'yes'){
?>
<label>Show me on yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="showme">
<?php
}

?>
</form>
```

So when we select the radio button "YES" than it must show `"showme"` radio button.

What do i wrong in here ?

**I want it to show before submitting the form**

Comment: Yes i have submit but it must be showed before submittin

Comment: You'll need some JS then for this. Some type of event listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for a perhaps front end solution without submitting the data to the server, that is you want to show the `radio` on check of another `radio` which can be achieved by client side scripting such as JavaScript or jQuery , but if it's that so than you can achieve that with pure CSS too...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMSav/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMSav/1/) (With `label`)

```
input[id="yes"] {
    display: none;
}

label[for="yes"] {
    display: none;
}

input[id="showyes"]:checked + label[for="yes"] {
    display: block;
}

input[id="showyes"]:checked + label[for="yes"] + input[id="yes"] {
    display: block;
}
```

Note: JavaScript/jQuery will fail if client has JS Disabled, well yes, JS can be the best way, but why use it if it can be easily accomplished with CSS only..

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you opt for a javascript side solution?

[Here's the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U4SdN/)

And, here's the markup:

```
<form method="POST">
<label>YES</label>
<input type="radio" name="yes" onclick='showNow(this);'>

<label class='showOnYes'>Show me on yes</label>
<input class='showOnYes' type="radio" name="showme">
</form>
```

and the javascript

```
function showNow(target) {
    if(target.checked); {
        var all = document.getElementsByClassName("showOnYes");
        for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
            all[i].style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
}
```

Finally some css:

```
.showOnYes {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Works, but there's another radio button that appears when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try, and it's styled. There are 2 radio buttons, but you can always remove one.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
div {
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
top: 40px;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
width: 280px;
padding: 10px;
color: black;
border: #0000cc 2px dashed;
display: none;
}
</style>

<script language="JavaScript">
function setVisibility(id, visibility) {
document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility;
}
</script>

</head>
<body >

<form action='' method='POST'>
<input type=radio name=type value='male' onclick="setVisibility('sub3', 'inline');setVisibility('sub4','none');";>Radio 1 <input type=radio name=type value='female' onclick="setVisibility('sub3', 'none');setVisibility('sub4','inline');";>Radio 2

<div id="sub3">
YES
</div>

<div id="sub4" >
NO
</div>
<br></form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Onclick if its YES then run this code with buttonId

```
document.getElementById("ButtonId").style.visibility="visible";
```